# Gatsby 5, TS and new Slice component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

Not sure if we are missing something obvious here.The documentation for slices says that you're supposed to be able to use children as usual for a slice component.
But whenever I add a child of any type. Like fragment, custom component or just plain HTML i get this:
[image: Gatsby 5 slice component children error]

The error goes away if I remove child props.
The rendered slice component looks like this:

```
const Layout = ({
  children,
  data,
}: SliceComponentProps<LayoutProps>) => {
  const { meetingPlace, menuCards, menuItem } =
    data.contentfulMeetingPlacePageHome;

  return (
    <>
      {meetingPlace && (
        <TabBar
          menuGroups={menuItem}
          menuCards={menuCards}
          logo={meetingPlace?.logo}
          socialMediaLinks={meetingPlace?.socialMediaLinks}
          meetingPlace={meetingPlace}
        />
      )}
      <div className="relative lg:px-28 xl:container xl:px-28">
        {meetingPlace && (
          <Header meetingPlace={meetingPlace} logo={meetingPlace?.logo} />
        )}
        {children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;

export const query = graphql`
  ...
`;
```

And

Inside gatsby-node I run the following code to create the slice:

```
actions.createSlice({
    id: 'layout',
    component: path.resolve('./src/components/layout/layout.tsx'),
  });
```

I get same error even I make a simple dummy slice component with no data as long as it a child of any kind.
Have the following gatsby packages in the project:

```
"gatsby": "5.3.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^8.3.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-inline-svg": "^1.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.3.1",
     "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^6.3.0",
```

Comment: It's a bug that will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/pull/37409

Comment: Thanx, that explains a lot.